# Function not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, safari, hyperlink

The function below works in FireFox and Internet Explorer but it does not work in Safari.
In Safari, when you click nothing happens.

How can I fix the function to work also in Safari?

I've checked that JavaScript is enabled (tested in 3 different machines already).

Thanks a ton

```
<script>
function win() {
$("#main").remove();

$("#content_target").html('<div  style="z-index:2;background:url(img/frame_main.png) no-repeat;text-align:left;width:726px;height:491px;"><div id="target" style="padding:5% 5%;float:left"></div>  </div>');

$("#target").load("myphp.php", {variable1: "myvariable", variable2: 12}, function(){

$("#my_div").css('background', 'url("img/img_ACTI.png") no-repeat');
});
}
</script>

<div onclick="javascript:win();" ><a href="#">Click me</a></div>
```

Comment: Technically, you should be using <script type="text/javascript"> although this is unlikely to be the cause of the problems. What happens if you put an alert on this function? Is the function feing executed when you click the div?

Comment: @James Wiseman  most "experts" (Doug Crockford for one) recommend that the "type" attribute on `<script>` tags be omitted unless you're explicitly trying to make the browser *ignore* your script (as in templating applications)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, putting the function into a click trigger...

```
<script>
    function win() {
    $("#main").remove();

    $("#content_target").html('<div  style="z-index:2;background:url(img/frame_main.png) no-repeat;text-align:left;width:726px;height:491px;"><div id="target" style="padding:5% 5%;float:left"></div>  </div>');

    $("#target").load("myphp.php", {variable1: "myvariable", variable2: 12}, function(){

    $("#my_div").css('background', 'url("img/img_ACTI.png") no-repeat');
    });
    }

    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
       win();
    });
    </script>

    <div id="clickMe" ><a href="#">Click me</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script>
    $("#clickme").click(function(event) {
        $("#main").remove();
        $("#content_target").html('<div style="z-index:2;background:url(img/frame_main.png) no-repeat;text-align:left;width:726px;height:491px;"><div id="target" style="padding:5% 5%;float:left"></div></div>');
        $("#target").load("myphp.php", {variable1: "myvariable", variable2: 12}, function(){
            $("#my_div").css('background', 'url("img/img_ACTI.png") no-repeat');
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>

<div><a href="#" id="clickme">Click me</a></div>
```